# How to avoid redirect when rewriting urls with wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, url-rewriting

I've set up a rewrite rule using WordPress own functions.
The rewrite code looks like this:

```
add_rewrite_rule('^testrule/(.+)?$', 'index.php?p=$matches[1]', 'top');
```

The rule works and everything, its just that whenever I go to that url, I get redirected which makes the URL changing and I do not want that to happen.

Any tips?

Comment: I think it has to do with that wordpress is rewriting my rule correctly, but as there is a rewrite for "index.php", the rewrite goes into place once more and thats why it changes the URL. Do anyone know how I can prevent this?

Comment: 2 years later : Any idea about how to solve this issue ?

Comment: Further 4 years on, an ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You probably should use [add_permastruct](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_permastruct) and [add_rewrite_tag](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_tag/) function it helped in my case. Although I had a little different situation, but the idea would be similar.

I had custom post type named "guide" and I needed custom URLs for it (different than the custom post name) plus I was using post slugs in URLs, here is my solution:

```
add_action('init', 'custom_permastruct_rewrite');
function custom_permastruct_rewrite() {
    global $wp_rewrite;

    $wp_rewrite->add_rewrite_tag("%guide_slug%", '([^/]+)', "post_type=guide&name=");
    $wp_rewrite->add_permastruct('my_rule', '/my_custom_name/%guide_slug%', false);
}
```

So when you go to the address:
http://example.com/my_custom_name/my_post_slug
under the above URL it displays content from:
http://example.com/?post_type=guide&name=my_post_slug
(without redirecting to the last address)

You can adapt the "post_type=guide&name=" to your needs, for instance you can look for post by id - so putting there "p=" would display content from: http://example.com/my_custom_name/24 to http://example.com/?p=24

Comment: The OP should make this the accepted answer. Thanks @Picard works a treat!

Answer (score 1):

some plugins (like Custom Permalinks) can redirect to `correct` url

```
add_rewrite_rule('^testrule/(.+)?$', 'index.php?disable_redirect=1&p=$matches[1]', 'top');

add_filter('query_vars', 'my_public_query_vars');
function my_public_query_vars($qv)
{
    $qv[] = 'disable_redirect';
    return $qv;
}

add_filter('wp_redirect', 'my_disable_redirect');
function my_disable_redirect($location)
{
    //var_dump(debug_backtrace());//if you want know who call redirect
    $disable_redirect = get_query_var('disable_redirect');
    if(!empty($disable_redirect)) return false;
    return $location;
}
```

Comment: That stopped the redirect, but now I got a 404 instead.